# keyboard keeps showing up when navigating back from other routes

Tags: flutter, dart

the main screen of my app currently has 5 tabs, and some of them have TextField
(the 2nd tab and the 3rd tab).

and all tabs have some menus that navigate to other routes.

when I get back from the other routes to the main screen, the keyboard pops up whether the tab has TextField or not.

I suspect that the reason is that TextField keeps gaining focus, but autofocus: false option doesn't work.

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A cheap way of doing this would be adding this to the main screen:

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState()
  if(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0){
     FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  }
}
```

But the actual issue lays somewhere else. (It is hard to know if yo do not show any code)

Comment: no this shouldn't be the way, as I said the main screen has some tabs that have TextField, and this code makes the TextFields not work properly(keyboard goes down when it's really needed)
I didn't share the code because I didn't do anything special with the keyboard action except for autofocus and thus the answer should work whatever the code is